# How to store previous selection in drop down menu in this case in html/php

Tags: html

I have drop down on change I have set a confirmation, clicking OK the form is submitted this part is working fine but on clicking cancel the selection still changes in drop down how do I prevent that.

How do I store my previous selection and set that when I click cancel to drop down?

```
<td style="width:auto;text-align:center">
<select class="form-control" name="Ostatus" onchange="if(confirm('Are you sure you want change the status?')){this.form.submit()}">                    
<option value="Uploaded" <?php if ($dispatchstatus == "Uploaded") echo "selected='selected'";?> >Uploaded</option>
<option value="Processing" <?php if ($dispatchstatus == "Processing") echo "selected='selected'";?> >Processing</option>
<option value="Dispatched" <?php if ($dispatchstatus == "Dispatched") echo "selected='selected'";?> >Dispatched</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Comment: Instead of doing an inline onchange event, I would call an external function. In this function, the first line would be to grab the current selected item. Then insert your current on change code afterwards. If !confirm, update the selected value to the stored value.

Comment: @EGC - Thanks but how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Well it depends on how you handle the backend/viewController in PHP, if you just want a fast way to store it why not use SESSION/COOKIES?

Comment: My page doesn't refresh to store the session.

Comment: Then are you sending the request through AJAX?

Comment: @Francis ask question My page reloads when I confirm the update but doesn't refresh when I click cancel.

Comment: Ow sorry for that, you mean the cancel is a reset?

Comment: The only possible way I think of is through JS,will that be suffice?

Comment: @Francisaskquestion: I am not sure how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the value/the selected option of the after resetting the form you just need to add click event to the reset button and store the selected option before resetting.

```js
document.getElementById("resetbtn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  var select = document.getElementById("selection");
  var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("mainform").reset();
  select.value = option;
});
```

```html
<form id="mainform">
  <select id="selection">
    <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="test">
  <button type="reset" value="Reset" id="resetbtn">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Please check this.. I have drop down on change I have set a confirmation, clicking OK the form is submitted this part is working fine but on clicking cancel the selection still changes in drop down how do I prevent that. So I am looking for a way to set my previous selection. Thanks!

Comment: I confuse on what your entire problem was. can you edit your question and add other relevant sources so I can pinpoint on what your problem is